# Using angular component more than once in single template - appending list inside of it

Tags: angular, components, angular-reactive-forms

I have this component that contains table (array of key-value elements) and one form below it. FOrm is used to append new values into table. There is Angular Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-key-value-table',
  templateUrl: './key-value-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./key-value-table.component.css']
})
export class KeyValueTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tableTitle: string;
  @Input() records: KeyValue[];
  @Input() prefix: string;

  newRecordForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newRecordForm = this.fb.group({
      key: ['',Validators.required],
      value: ['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

  deleteFromList(index: number) {
    this.records.splice(index, 1);
  }

  addRow(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    if(this.newRecordForm.invalid)
      return;

    const newRecord = Object.assign({}, this.newRecordForm.value);
    if(this.records.filter(elt=>elt.key === newRecord.key).length)
      return
    else {
      this.records.push(newRecord);
      formDirective.resetForm();
      this.newRecordForm.reset();
    }
  }
}
```

And there is HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Identyfikator</th>
    <th scope="col" class="wide">{{tableTitle}}</th>
    <th scope="col">Edytuj</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let record of records; let index = index">
    <th scope="row">{{record.key}}</th>
    <td class="wide">{{record.value}}</td>
    <td>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteFromList(index)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="index==(records.length-1)" (click)="moveLower(index)"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="index==0" (click)="moveHigher(index)"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="table-record-form">
  <form [formGroup]="newRecordForm" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addRow(formDirective)">
    <mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
      <input #key matInput placeholder="Identyfikator" formControlName="key" required>
      <mat-hint align="end">{{key.value?.length || 0}}/50</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
      <input #value matInput placeholder="Treść" formControlName="value" required>
      <mat-hint align="end">{{value.value?.length || 0}}/250</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button name="submit-button" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="newRecordForm.invalid">
      Dodaj rekord
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I put two of them in one template, and try to append table (with inputs and click on the button) both of the lists are getting appended. Is it normal behavior? How to get rid of it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'both of the lists are getting appending'. You only have one list right (the table)? What is the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two lists with the same dataset, i.e your `records`, then your `addRow` function is going to apply to both of these tables. What I'd recommend is having a separate dataset such as `records2` which you can then use in this second table.